# Proof for if $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)=(x-b_1)(x-b_2)...(x-b_n)$, then $a_k=b_k$ for all $k$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I tried proving the equality above. This is my proof:

We prove the equation by induction. If $n=1$, the equality holds. Suppose that it holds for $n=k$. Then $x-a_{k+1}=x-b_{k+1}$ whenever $x$ is not equal to $a_1,...,a_k$. Then $a_{k+1}=b_{k+1} $.

Comment: The claim is false. Obviously, $(b_k)$ may be  a permutation of $(a_k)$.

Comment: It matters over what your polynomials are, if it's a UFD (this is basically what you're trying to prove) i. e $\Bbb{R} [X], \Bbb{C} [X] $ then each irreducible is a prime so $x-a_i$ divides $x-b_j$ so since $x-b_j$ is prime so $x-a_j=c(x-b_j) $ but clearly $c=1$ so $a_i=b_j$

Comment: @kingW3 You don't need to be over a UFD for polynomials of this form to factor uniquely, just over a domain.  Polynomials define functions, and if, say, $a_i$ did not appear on the right hand side for some $i$, then $\prod_j a_i-b_j =0 would be a product of non-zero terms, hence you would have found a zero divisor.  You need to say slightly more to deal with multiplicity, but it is essentially the division algorithm plus induction.

Comment: Your proof works if the given equation is meant to hold for all $k$, for fixed sequences $a,\,b$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after possibly reordering.  I wouldn't use induction. This is because a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots.

Answer (score 0):

If $$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)=(x-b_1)(x-b_2)...(x-b_n)$$ is true $\forall x$, and $$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)(x-a)=(x-b_1)(x-b_2)...(x-b_n)(x-b)$$ is true $\forall x$, then $\forall x\notin\{a_1,\dots,a_n,a,b\}$:

$(x-a)=\frac{(x-b_1)(x-b_2)...(x-b_n)}{(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)}(x-b)$

$\therefore x-a=x-b \qquad\forall x\notin\{a_1,\dots,a_n,a,b\}$

$\therefore a=b$.